# Performance analysis on SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Which will perform better?

Ouery 1:

```
select (select a from innertable I where i.val=o.val)
       , val1, val2 
from outertable o
```

Query 2:

```
select i.a
       ,o.val1
       ,o.val2 
from outertable o 
     join innertable i on i.val=o.val
```

Why ? Please advise.

Comment: Don't know about oracle in particular, but the second would perform better in MySQL.  The first uses the sub-select that would force the engine to create a temporary table (and locking innertable for the duration).  Use joins when you can, it's what the engine was designed for.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark them and see?

Comment: In general, you can use EXPLAIN to see what the query planner will do for a given query

Comment: Are those fields indexed ? Then use explain too see which performs better

Comment: @amccausl: that might be true for the limited query optimizer in MySQL, but I wouldn't be surprised if Oracle used the same execution plan for both statements.

Comment: @AruM: those two statements are **not** equivalent! The first one will **only** work if there is a 1:1 relation between innertable and outertable. It will fail if there is more than one row in `innertable` for the same value of `val`.

Answer (score 4):

As Ollie suggests, the only definitive way to determine which of two queries is more efficient is to benchmark the two approaches using your data since the performance of the two alternatives is likely to depend on data volumes, data structures, what indexes are present, etc.

In general, the two queries that you posted will return different results.  Unless you are guaranteed that every row in `outertable` has exactly one corresponding row in `innertable`, the two queries will return a different number of rows.  The first query will return a row for every row in `outertable` with a NULL as the first column if there is no matching row in `innertable`.  The second query will not return anything if there is no matching row in `innertable`.  Similarly, if there are multiple matching rows in `innertable` for any particular row in `outertable`, the first query will return an error while the second query will return multiple rows for that row in `outertable`.

If you are confident that the two queries return identical result sets in your particular case because you can guarantee that there is exactly one row in `innertable` for every row in `outertable` (in which case it is at least somewhat odd that your data model separates the tables), the second option would be the much more natural way to write the query and thus the one for which the optimizer is most likely to find the more efficient plan.

Comment: +1, although the 1-1 relationship is not mandatory: most likely `innertable` is a lookup table such that val is its primary key. In this case the first query will return the same result as an OUTER join. If `val` is not nullable and there is a foreign key relationship, both queries are guaranteed to return the same results.

Comment: First one is co related subquery -Internally, correlated subqueries are very expensive to process because the inner query must be executed for every row returned by the outer query .